# Java EE, Hibernate, MySql UTF-8 query doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, utf-8, wildfly

So I have set up hibernate with Wildfly and MySql.

Querying works, but have problem querying UTF-8 character names.

On MySql:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname = "ნიკა";
```

Doesn't result in empty set.

While in java:

```
Session session = HibernateUtils.getSession();

String name = request.getParameter("name");

CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<UsersEntity> query = builder.createQuery(UsersEntity.class);
Root<UsersEntity> usersRoot = query.from(UsersEntity.class);
query.select(usersRoot)
        .where(builder.equal(usersRoot.get("firstname"), name));

List<UsersEntity> list = session.createQuery(query).list();

session.close();

writeUsers(list, response.getWriter());
```

Results in an empty set when querying `localhost:8080/main?name=ნიკა`

How do I fix this ?

**UPDATE:**

I also have issue that when querying all data and displaying them
non english characters are replaced with question marks.

**UPDATE 2:**

This code results in showing up question marks on browser:

```
response.getWriter().write("ნიკა ჩხარტიშვილი");
```

While this one works properly:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write("ნიკა ჩხარტიშვილი");
```

When querying database with this query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='ნიკა'` database receives question marks instead of `ნიკა` (That's what shows up in wireshark).

I think it's wildfly issue because it received UTF-8 correctly but sends question marks unless it's specified to send UTF-8.

Comment: and if for the test you could hardcode the name in the code, does it work also. If it works like that, it's the translation done by the browser.

Comment: @davejal Hardcoding it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Your SQL example uses `firstname = "ნიკა"`. Your URL example uses `localhost:8080/main?name=ნიკა`.What happens if you close the session after the `writeUsers` call? What does the `writeUsers` call do?

Comment: It just outputs the names into the `response.getWriter()`, it mustn't be the case because `localhost:8080/main?name=dato` works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.

First connection to client wasn't `UTF-8`.
Fixed it with:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

This works for one servlet though.
Updated wildfly `standalone.xml` configuration file to

```
<servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="UTF-8">
    <jsp-config/>
    <websockets/>
</servlet-container>
```

Added `default-encoding` property to `servlet-container`, now every response will have default `UTF-8` encoding.

JDBC Communication wasn't `UTF-8`.

Fixed with updating `connection.url`, appended

`?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` at the end.

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cnick?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
```

When last time I did this I thought it didn't work because what I was querying wasn't in the database. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This is because URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.

If your call to the server is from javascript you should encode your name value with encodeURIComponent("ნიკა") , your call should look like this:

```
localhost:8080/main?name=%E1%83%9C%E1%83%98%E1%83%99%E1%83%90
```

If you are just pasting the URL to the brownser just do it as usual

```
localhost:8080/main?name=ნიკა
```

and then in your server after you get the name value from the request you encode it again as UTF-8 like this:

```
 //String name = request.getParameter("name");
 String name = new String(request.getParameter("name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get question marks when reading from a MySQL database, see [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- The column in the database is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4). Fix this.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

The question marks were generated when *INSERTing* into the database, so the original text cannot be recovered.

I'm pretty sure that any mention of `"ISO-8859-1"` is going to be wrong.  `%E1%83%9C` is the urlencoding of `ნ`.  Fetching the `name` *should* undo that for you, without any action on your part.  Hence, doing `getBytes("ISO-8859-1")` is asking for `ნიკა` to be provided in that encoding.  But that encoding only covers Western Europe.  I suggest trying

```
new String(request.getParameter("name").getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

(Is that Java?  Or what?)

Comment: When I select from command line no question marks are present. And select with where clause works properly. I think it must be connection issue.

Comment: I just checked another thing. I logged names on server and they are properly encoded but when sending to browser they are questionmarked.

Comment: There is no _direct_ connection from MySQL to the browser.  It _must_ be going through some app, and that app must need fixing.

Comment: It doesn't work. Literal or encoded server sends query with question marks to mysql. How to make sure connection to database is using UTF-8 ?

Comment: See "Best Practice" in they link.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Hibernate @Type attribute,Based on  your requirement you can customize the annotation and apply on top of the fied.
like :

```
public class PhoneNumberType implements UserType {
@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[]{Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER};
}

@Override
public Class returnedClass() {
    return PhoneNumber.class;
}

// other methods
}
```

First, the null SafeGet method:

```
@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, 
SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
int countryCode = rs.getInt(names[0]);
 if (rs.wasNull())
    return null;
 int cityCode = rs.getInt(names[1]);
int number = rs.getInt(names[2]);
PhoneNumber employeeNumber = new PhoneNumber(countryCode, cityCode, number);
 return employeeNumber;
 }
```

Next, the null SafeSet method:

```
@Override
 public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, 
  int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) 
   throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (Objects.isNull(value)) {
    st.setNull(index, Types.INTEGER);
    } else {
    PhoneNumber employeeNumber = (PhoneNumber) value;
    st.setInt(index,employeeNumber.getCountryCode());
    st.setInt(index+1,employeeNumber.getCityCode());
    st.setInt(index+2,employeeNumber.getNumber());
  }
 }
```

Finally, we can declare our custom PhoneNumberType in our OfficeEmployee entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OfficeEmployee")
 public class OfficeEmployee {

  @Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "country_code"), 
  @Column(name = "city_code"), @Column(name = "number") })
  @Type(type = "com.baeldung.hibernate.customtypes.PhoneNumberType")
   private PhoneNumber employeeNumber;

 // other fields and methods
  }
```

This might solve your problem, This will work for all database.
if  you want more info refer :: 
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types

Answer (score 0):

There are below common locations where UTF8 encoding is to be enabled

**1)** Make sure you create the database and its tables using character set **utf8** and collation **utf8_unicode_ci**

**2) Under hibernate configuration file**

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

**3) Under main html template header section**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

**4) Under apache tomcat server.xml**

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```